# Different Table Cells Widths per Row

Tags: html, css

I want to have different cell `width`s per row but cannot seems to achieve this neatly:

So for example, this doesn't work:

```css
.tg {
  width: 100%
}
.tg td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td width="80%">Cell 1</td>
    <td width="20%">Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Cell 1</td>
    <td width="80%">Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but this will:

```css
.tg {
  width: 100%
}
.tg td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td width="80%">Cell 1</td>
    <td width="20%">Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%">Cell 1</td>
    <td width="80%">Cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`colspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan)?

Comment: I have tried to implement that but it didn't work. It seems that when the rows are in the same table the widths are ignored. However, I am but a simple coder and may have incorrectly implemented it, perhaps you could show me by altering my code? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/r9vwzya3/

Answer (score 0):

The first example will not work because the first row is establishing the dimensions of the table.  The second row size dimension declarations are going against the nature of tabular display.  If you must use tables instead of a table-less approach such as floating div elements you would have to use colspans to get the display results closer to what you are trying to achieve.

The second works because you are splitting the elements into 2 separate tables so each is establishing their dimensions with their respective first rows.

The colspan approach would looks something similar to:

```css
table td {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%" colspan="3">Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%" colspan="3">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
    <td width="25%">Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked well but means that cells must be exact divisions of other cells if that makes any sense. It stops me from having complete control over individual cells widths. If its not too much trouble could you show me sample code of a couple of rows emulating the effect i'm looking for using divs? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, this response is long over due.  Although this is likely solved many times over I thought I would also mention that it might be floating divs that make more sense for the particular solution.  Then you could also add dynamic sizing via javascript.  However I believe I answered the original question with the example.